# Do Switzerland and the UK have 'different time' or 'different times' (the time zone each is in)?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

'Time' is

> 'the system of recording hours used in different parts of the world'

and is uncountable, says the Cambridge Dictionary Online.

[definition of 'time' in the Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/time#british-1-1-2)

Really?!

Should it be

> 'Switzerland and the UK have different time.'

then, or rather

> 'Switzerland and the UK have different times.'

, which sounds more correct… ?

Comment: I can't count the number of times that a dictionary definition was incompletely or inaccurately stated.

Comment: Switzerland and the UK are in different time zones.  (As Ricky suggests.)  Of course, in earlier **times** each city had it's own time reference, unrelated to others.

Comment: This usage of _time_ (always with some kind of modifier before it, like _Greenwich Mean Time_ and _daylight saving time_ in the dictionary examples) is indeed pretty much always singular. I’m not sure I quite agree that it’s _uncountable_ as such, but it requires a **very** contrived context to be pluralised. Your example is not such an example, since _time(s)_ would not be used at all in idiomatic English there: _time zones_ would. But you could make one up: “Yesterday I was on London time; two hours ago I was on Beijing time; now I’m on NZ time. All these… _times_ are messing with my head!”

Answer (score 3):

Time is a property of space.

The standard way of pointing out the difference would be

> Switzerland and the U.K. are in different time zones.

The informal way of explaining why Kevin and Linda look a bit groggy would be

> They're still on Swiss time. Give them a a day or two to adjust.